# Glassfish v3 servlet container

Tags: glassfish

I'm wondering what is the servlet container in Glassfish. In some sources I saw that Glassfish uses something like Grizzly, but Grizzly is a web framework:

> The Grizzly NIO and Web framework has been designed to help developers to take advantage of the Java™ NIO API. Grizzly's goal is to help developers to build scalable and robust servers using NIO and we are also offering extended framework components: Web Framework (HTTP/S), Bayeux Protocol, Servlet, HttpService OSGi and Comet.

What does it mean? Does Glassfish use Grizzly as web container. Or maybe Tomcat, and Grizzly as  an extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grizzly is the HTTP connector. Glassfish uses a fork of Tomcat's engine (Catalina) as servlet container. An easy evidence is checking the stacktrace when some exception occurs in your business code. You'll see `org.apache.catalina.*` deep down in the trace, between the `com.sun.grizzly.*` lines and the lines of your own business code. It typically look like this:

```
...
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Glassfish is not the only which uses Catalina by the way, JBoss AS and IBM WebSphere also use it.

Comment: JBoss can also use Jetty. WebSphere Application Server (not CE=Geronimo) have no deals with Tomcat.